# swift url Session post request with parameters and image (Multipart Form-Data Requests )

Tags: ios, swift

I want to post image with parameters to server with url session, Here what I try -

```
var groupImg: UIImage? 
 var grupId: String = ""
var grupName: String = ""
var creator: String = "xahiw"
var lati = "30.6425°N"
var long = "76.8173°E"
```

and here's the code on the action of button

```
@IBAction func onClickSubmitBtn(_ sender: Any) {
           let url = URL(string: "http://example/api/create")!
            var request = URLRequest(url: url)
            request.setValue("Application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            let parameters: [String: Any] = [
                "name": grupName,
                "category": grupId,
                "picture": groupImg!,
                "createdBy": creator,
                "lat": lati,
                "lng": long
    
            ]
            request.httpBody = parameters.percentEncoded()
    
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
                guard let data = data,
                    let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse,
                    error == nil else {
                        print("error", error ?? "Unknown error")
                        return
                }
    
                guard (200 ... 299) ~= response.statusCode else {
                    print("statusCode should be 2xx, but is \(response.statusCode)")
                    print("response = \(response)")
                    return
                }
    
                let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                print("responseString = \(String(describing: responseString))")
            }
    
            task.resume()
        
        
    }
    extension Dictionary {
        func percentEncoded() -> Data? {
            return map { key, value in
                let escapedKey = "\(key)".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed) ?? ""
                let escapedValue = "\(value)".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed) ?? ""
                return escapedKey + "=" + escapedValue
                }
                .joined(separator: "&")
                .data(using: .utf8)
        }
    }
    
    extension CharacterSet {
        static let urlQueryValueAllowed: CharacterSet = {
            let generalDelimitersToEncode = ":#[]@"
            let subDelimitersToEncode = "!$&'()*+,;="
    
            var allowed = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
            allowed.remove(charactersIn: "\(generalDelimitersToEncode)\(subDelimitersToEncode)")
            return allowed
        }()
    }
```

but i unable to post data i get the status code -- 400 when i click on button,  can anyone tell me how to do this, is it done with different way (upload image with parameters )

Comment: You can't just add a binary object, like a UIImage into your parameters.  You will need to confirm how the server wants the data.  The image will probably need to be base64 encoded.  If the server isn't accepting JSON you may also need to set up your POST data as mime-multipart with the parameter values separate from the base64 encoded image.

Comment: @Paulw11 please tell me how can i do it .

Comment: Simplest way is to get your request working in Postman and then have Postman generate the Swift code for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a simple function to create a body for your request.

```
func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: String], filePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: Data?, boundary: String) -> Data {
    var body = Data();

    for (key, value) in parameters {
        body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
        body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
        body.appendString("\(value)\r\n")
    }

    let filename = "image_name.jpg"
    let mimetype = "image/jpg"

    body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")

    if let filePath = filePathKey, let imageData = imageDataKey {
        body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePath)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
        body.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
        body.append(imageData)
        body.appendString("\r\n")
        body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")
    }

    return body
}
```

and assign it to the request body.

```
request.httpBody = createBodyWithParameters(parameters: ["key":"Value"], filePathKey: "file", imageDataKey: imageData, boundary: "Boundary-\(NSUUID().uuidString)");
```

For appending string to the data, you can use an extension like this.

```
extension Data {
    mutating func appendString(_ string: String) {
        let data = string.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: true)
        append(data!)
    }
}
```

Comment: i got error --> Value of type 'Data' has no member 'appendString'. and when i use append instead appendString then --> Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '(String)'

Comment: @xahiw apologies, I didn't realise that a extension was being used in my code. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: i got error in http body --> Use of unresolved identifier 'imageData'

Comment: that is the `Data` object of the `UIImage` you want to post.

Comment: i use my image instead of image data then i get error --> Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage?' to expected argument type 'Data?'

Comment: You need to convert the image to `Data` object. In swift 4.2, the conversion methods are simplified to `image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)` and `image.pngData()` based on type of your image.

Comment: thanks a lot! for help me but it doesn't solve my problem after use your code it gives me the status code 413 --> statusCode should be 2xx, but is 413

Comment: 413 is Payload Too Large (RFC 7231). How large is the `Data` that you're sending? Check that against your server configuration, which has parameters that dictate the largest asset size that can be uploaded. Try `jpegData` with lower quality setting (e.g. 0.8 or 0.7). Or increase max asset size in your server configuration.

Answer (score 1):

```
class func request(withImages path:APIMethods, method:URLMethod, token : String?, headers:[String:String]?, parameters: [String:Any]?,imageNames : [String], images:[Data], completion: @escaping(Any?, Error?, Bool)->Void) {


    

    var stringUrl = “abc.com”
    if method == .get, let lastPath = parameters?.values.first as? String {
        stringUrl += lastPath
    }else{
        stringUrl += token ?? ""
    }


    // generate boundary string using a unique per-app string
    let boundary = UUID().uuidString

    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)

    print("\n\ncomplete Url :-------------- ",stringUrl," \n\n-------------: complete Url")
    guard let url = URL(string: stringUrl) else { return }
    var request = URLRequest(url: url)
    request.httpMethod = method.rawValue

    if headers != nil{
        print("\n\nHeaders :-------------- ",headers as Any,"\n\n --------------: Headers")
        for (key, value) in headers! {
            request.setValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: key)

        }
    }

    // Set Content-Type Header to multipart/form-data

    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    var data = Data()
    if parameters != nil{
        for(key, value) in parameters!{
          
            data.append("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
            data.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
            data.append("\(value)".data(using: .utf8)!)
        }
    }
    for (index,imageData) in images.enumerated() {
        
        data.append("\r\n--\(boundary)\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        data.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(imageNames[index])\"; filename=\"\(imageNames[index])\"\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        data.append("Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)
        data.append(imageData)
    }

   
    data.append("\r\n--\(boundary)--\r\n".data(using: .utf8)!)

    
    session.uploadTask(with: request, from: data, completionHandler: { data, response, error in

        if let checkResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse{
            if checkResponse.statusCode == 200{
                guard let data = data, let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: [JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments]) else {
                    completion(nil, error, false)
                    return
                }
                let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
                print("\n\n---------------------------\n\n"+jsonString+"\n\n---------------------------\n\n")
                print(json)
                completion(json, nil, true)
            }else{
                guard let data = data, let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) else {
                    completion(nil, error, false)
                    return
                }
                let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!
                print("\n\n---------------------------\n\n"+jsonString+"\n\n---------------------------\n\n")
                print(json)
                completion(json, nil, false)
            }
        }else{
            guard let data = data, let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: []) else {
                completion(nil, error, false)
                return
            }
            completion(json, nil, false)
        }

    }).resume()

}

extension Data {


    mutating func append(_ string: String, using encoding: String.Encoding = .utf8) {
        if let data = string.data(using: encoding) {
            append(data)
        }
    }
}
```