# In Swift (iOS app), what is the correct way to post data to my .net WebAPI which has [FromForm] parameters and uses autobinding?

Tags: ios, swift, .net-core, fetch-api, webapi

**Please Note: Not A Duplicate**

Please read all of this, before you decide my question is a duplicate, because I've searched for answers and read numerous on SO, but none of them address the issue of having `[FromForm]` WebAPI binding.

I have the following WebAPI method in a Controller:

```
[HttpPost("SetScreenName")]
public ActionResult SetScreenName([FromForm] String guid, [FromForm] String screenName)
```

The user can simply pass in a guid and a screenName to set the screenName for the user profile.

I can call this easily from JavaScript `fetch` using the following code:

```
const formDataX = new FormData();
formDataX.append("guid","fakeguid-here");
formDataX.append("screenName", "newoneForTest");

fetch("https://localhost:7103/User/SetScreenName", {
  method: 'POST',
  body: formDataX,
})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Now, I need to know how to make a call to this same WebAPI method using Swift (in a iOS App / SwiftUI)

**Here's What I've Tried**

I've been trying to get thru this for a couple of days and would always get errors back from my WebAPI stating that one or both of the parameters (guid, screenName) were missing.

Here's a list of SO answers and snippets of code I've attempted to draw the answer from:

1. [swift url Session post request with parameters and image (Multipart Form-Data Requests )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66998731/swift-url-session-post-request-with-parameters-and-image-multipart-form-data-re)
2. [HTTP Request in Swift with POST method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364914/http-request-in-swift-with-post-method)

Got the following code which I partially used, but still failed :
**Note**: the failure was always that one or both params were missing.

```
let url = URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/post")!
var request = URLRequest(url: url)
request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.httpMethod = "POST"
```

3. [How can I build a URL with query parameters containing multiple values for the same key in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34060754/how-can-i-build-a-url-with-query-parameters-containing-multiple-values-for-the-s)

Tried following code but WebAPI would only recognized the first param (`guid`):

```
url.append(queryItems:  [URLQueryItem(name: "guid", value: "\(guid)"), URLQueryItem(name: "screenName", value: "\(screenName)")])
```

4. [How to make HTTP Post request with JSON body in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31937686/how-to-make-http-post-request-with-json-body-in-swift/72469385?r=Saves_UserSavesList#72469385)

Tried to encode the params as JSON using code from that answer:

```
var outData = userData(uuid.uuidString.lowercased(), screenName)
var je = JSONEncoder()
  guard let jsonData = try? je.encode(outData) else{
     print ("encode FAILURE!")
     return false
}
```

Result data looked like:
`{"guid"="5c290f79-73a2-4bba-b34e-4d68c9d73ff7","screenName"="sallafootam"}`

None of these solutions worked and my WebAPI would always indicate that one or more params (`guid` or `screenName`) were missing.

What is the definitive set up to post to my WebAPI method using Swift?

Comment: Your server is expecting a `x-www-form-urlencoded` body.

Comment: @Paulw11 I appreciate you mentioning that so I can do further research.  It is interesting however, that I didn't need that value set `request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")`  on the final `request` object, but I did have to have the exact format shown in my answer.  
If you have any other resources I could read about that, please let me know.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the simplest setup that I finally discovered that works for my WebAPI with those `[FromForm]` parameters:

```
request.httpMethod = "POST"
var finalData = "guid=\(uuid.uuidString.lowercased())&screenName=\(screenName)"
request.httpBody = finalData.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
```

Notice that the values look like a normal QueryString, but you cannot add these to the queryString because they will not be bound on the WebAPI side.

They have to be created, just as I show them in the snippet above and then added to the `httpBody` of the `request`.